# JavaScript modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress site loading a JS file named `script.js`, which is loaded always. In that file I have this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.demo-2").on("click", function (e) {
    var options = {
      width: "1200px",
      height: "100%",
      closeCross: true,
      escapeKey: true,
      beforeOpen: function () {
        $("body").addClass("popupOpened")
      },
    };
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).simplePopup({type: "html", htmlSelector: "#myPopup"});
  });
});
```

The HTML code for the page `/product/experience`:

```
<button href="#" class="button demo-2">Más info</button>
<div id="myPopup">
    <h2><?php _e( 'More information about', 'exp-theme' ); ?></h2> 
    <h3><?php the_title( ); ?></h3>
    <?php 
        if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "es"){
            echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="705" title="+Info experiencias"]');
        }else{
            echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="40" title="Contacto"]');
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

If I load that page directly, the modal works correctly. But if I'm in the home and go to `/product/experience`, the modal is not working until I reload `/product/experience`.

I don't know which is the better approach. Load the function only in this page? Maybe use another way to do it instead `$(document).ready`?

Comment: you never use `options`, why define it?

Comment: You're right, but this not solve the problem. The options are there because i'm trying simplePopup library.

Comment: How are you loading the JS file? You have to ensure you make it depend on jquery so it always loads after it's loaded.